# Get the actual structure size before alignment

Tags: windbg

So it turns out that both `dt struct` and `?? sizeof struct` return the total size the struct occupies in memory after alignment.

Is there a way to get the actual size of the struct before alignment?

I need this functionality for a function that returns the actual size of a field within a struct. For example:

```c
__declspec(align(64)) struct ALIGNED_STRUCT {
    char field;
}
```

running `?? sizeof(ALIGNED_STRUCT)` one should get 0x40 which makes it hard to deduce the actual size of the internal field.

edit:

command outputs:

```
2:001> dt -v ALIGNED_STRUCT 
test!ALIGNED_STRUCT 
struct ALIGNED_STRUCT, 1 elements, 0x40 bytes
   +0x000 field            : Char

3:001> ?? sizeof(ALIGNED_STRUCT)
0x40
```

Comment: the `sizeof`  operator returns the total size of the structure, hence the size of the structure in memory. It accounts for field alignement in the structure (thus it does **not** return the total size of the fields of the structure).

Comment: interesting, i just run some tests and verified this. I have updated the question to more useful

Comment: Could you post the full output of `dt`? I'm too lazy to build a sample app myself.

Comment: *for a function that returns the actual size of a field within a struct* : you can `sizeof` a structure field in Windbg, although the interpreter is picky and won't let you do the equivalent of linux `#FIELD_SIZEOF` (you have to replace 0 with a valid mapped address...). So technically, to answer "At which offset does the last field end?":  `?? #FIELD_OFFSET(struct_type, field_name) + sizeof ((struct_type*)addr)->field_name`  (where `addr` is a valid address...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- there isn't a way to return the structure size "before alignment".  That's not really meaningful in any case.  The compiler is always using the aligned size.  The symbols have the aligned size.  That's the size of the type.

If you are looking for things like the "size of an internal field", there are numerous ways to accomplish this.  As mentioned in comments, you can do the quick dirty EE sizeof thing:

```
    dx sizeof(((ALIGNED_STRUCT *)0)->field)
```

You can also get **full access** to the underlying type system via the data model APIs (in either a C/C++ extension or in JavaScript) which will allow you to find out pretty much whatever you want about the types: their fields, sizes, offsets, function parameter types, template arguments, etc...

From C/C++, you can:

- QI for *IDebugHostSymbols* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgmodel/nn-dbgmodel-idebughostsymbols)
- Get an *IDebugHostModule* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgmodel/nn-dbgmodel-idebughostmodule) for the module containing your structure by calling the *FindModuleByName* method.
- Get an *IDebugHostType* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgmodel/nn-dbgmodel-idebughosttype) for the type you want to inquire about (e.g.: ALIGNED_STRUCT) by calling *FindTypeByName*
- Enumerate its fields with *EnumerateChildren*, getting an *IDebugHostField* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgmodel/nn-dbgmodel-idebughostfield) for each
- Get the offset of such field by calling *GetOffset*
- Get the type of each field by calling *GetType*, getting you back to another *IDebugHostType*
- Get the size of the field by calling *GetSize*

That might look **something like** this:

```
ComPtr<IDebugHostSymbols> spHostSymbols;  /* QI this off IDebugClient, etc... */
ComPtr<IDebugHostModule> spMyModule;
if (FAILED(spHostSymbols->FindModuleByName(USE_CURRENT_HOST_CONTEXT, L"myModule", &spMyModule)))
{
    return ...;
}

ComPtr<IDebugHostType> spType;
if (FAILED(spMyModule->FindTypeByName(L"ALIGNED_STRUCT", &spType)))
{
    return ...;
}

ComPtr<IDebugHostType> spType; /* get the type of an object */

//
// Enumerate every field of this type.  Note thiat this *WILL NOT* enumerate 
// fields of base classes!
//
ComPtr<IDebugHostSymbolEnumerator> spEnum;
if (SUCCEEDED(spType->EnumerateChildren(SymbolField, nullptr, &spEnum)))
{
    ComPtr<IDebugHostSymbol> spFieldSymbol;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    while (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = spEnum->GetNext(&spFieldSymbol);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            ComPtr<IDebugHostField> spField;
            if (SUCCEEDED(spFieldSymbol.As(&spField))) /* should always succeed */
            {
                // spField is each field of the type in turn
            }

            ULONG64 fieldOffset;
            if (SUCCEEDED(spField->GetOffset(&fieldOffset)) /* won't succeed on static fields */
            {
                // fieldOffset is the offset of the field within the type
            }

            ComPtr<IDebugHostType> spFieldType;
            if (SUCCEEDED(spField->GetType(&spFieldType))
            {
                ULONG64 fieldSize;
                if (SUCCEEDED(spFieldType->GetSize(&fieldSize)))
                {
                    // fieldSize contains the size (aligned) of the field's type
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // hr == E_BOUNDS : we hit the end of the enumerator
    // hr == E_ABORT  : user requested interruption, propagate upwards immediately
}
```

For C++, this can be made significantly easier by using the C++17 helper library on GitHub (https://github.com/microsoft/WinDbg-Libraries/blob/master/DbgModelCppLib/DbgModelClientEx.h)

That might look **something like**:

```
Module myModule(HostContext::DeferredCurrent(), L"myModule");
Type alignedStruct(myModule, L"ALIGNED_STRUCT");

//
// The below will *NOT* enumerate fields of base classes.  You must explicitly
// recurse if you want such.
//
for(Field f : alignedStruct.Fields())
{
    //
    // Get the offset and size of each field. 
    //
    ULONG64 fieldOffset = f.GetOffset();
    ULONG64 fieldSize = f.Type().Size();
}
```

In JavaScript (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/native-objects-in-javascript-extensions-type-objects), this would look like:

- Call *host.getModuleType* to get a type object for the structure (e.g.: ALIGNED_STRUCT)
- Get access to the field in question by accessing the named property of *fields* on the type (e.g.: myType.fields.field_name)
- Get the offset of of such field by accessing the *offset* property
- Get the type of each field by accessing the *type* property
- Get the size of the field by accessing the *size* property of its type

That might look **something like**:

```
var myType = host.getModuleType("myModule", "ALIGNED_STRUCT");
var fields = myType.fields;

//
// In JavaScript, fields has properties named according to each field.  If
// you want to enumerate, get the property names and access those keys.
//
var fieldNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fields);
for (var fieldName of fieldNames)
{
    var field = fields[fieldName];
    
    //
    // Get the offset and size of each field...
    //
    var fieldOffset = field.offset;
    var fieldSize = field.type.size;
}
```

In either of these cases, you would need to manually recurse base classes if you're looking at C++ objects where fields are contained in base classes.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

William has provided a comprehensive answer this answer is just a practical example of that

```
0:000> dx @$stru
@$stru           : Pcb _KPROCESS (+ 0x0)
    name             : Pcb
    type             : _KPROCESS
    locationKind     : member
    offset           : 0x0
0:000> dx @$stru.type.fields.Header.type.size
@$stru.type.fields.Header.type.size : 0x18
0:000>
```